# About AWS Route53 public host zone and private host zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, dig

I registered a domain with test.com on Route53. In the public hosted zone I created a record for the subdomain with dev.test.com. I used an alias and set it to an NLB with a fixed IP. I also created a record for the dev.test.com subdomain in the private hosted zone, used an alias, and set it to the VPC endpoint.

The following problem occurred:

I was able to get a fixed IP (public IP) from my local PC with the following command, but sometimes I could also get the private IP of the VPC endpoint.

What caused the private IP of the VPC endpoint to be obtained with the following command?

```
$> dig dev.test.com A
```

What caused the private IP of the VPC endpoint to be obtained with the following command?

```
$> dig dev.test.com A
```